# What is the meaning of 1=2 when copying database structure?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, create-table

I've come across

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table where 1=2;
```

What is the meaning of the `where 1=2` condition and what function does it perform?

Comment: It's a typo.  It should be `1=0` ;)  *(It's just a 'hack' to create a table based on a query, ensuring that you get the right data-types, but guaranteeing that you get no rows in the new table.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1=2` always evaluates as false. This is a common trick to utilize the create as select to copy a table's structure without copying any of its rows (as none of them will pass the test of `1=2`).

Answer (score 1):

Just it will copy the structure of a `table` not `data` present in a `table`. `1=0 or 1=2` will always returns false in where clause so `select query` doesn't return any `rows` from table it's just a trick for create a `table` as like another `table` in your `schema` .

Comment: `1=0` is infinitely superior :)

Answer (score 1):

1=2 essentially results in none of the current records in the old table being selected when you create the new table and thus that you only use the structure of the old table to make the new table.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE 1=2` means a false condition WHERE no rows will be taken from the table and the target table will be similar to the source table except data